# IIS 8.5 - Feature Delegation setting with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to set feature delegation to read/write using PowerShell. On a server with a default installation of IIS 8.5:

```
$property = @{
    Filter   = "/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication"
    Force    = $true
    PSPath   = "IIS:/"
    Value    = "Allow"
    Metadata = "OverrideMode"
}
Set-WebConfiguration @property
```

The command runs but the setting does not change. If I navigate to IIS > Management > Feature Delegation, Windows Authentication is still showing 'Read Only', **not** 'Read/Write'

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out the problem. This may help someone in the future, the issue is with `Metadata = "OverrideMode"`, overrideMode is **case sensitive!**. Correct example:

```
Metadata = "overrideMode"
```

Which is odd for Windows Server 2012 R2 OS.